# How to monitor when files in a directory are touched (opened, closed, altered)?

Tags: python, macos

I'm a Python/programming beginner (I have the basics down, but a lot to learn). As a fun project, I want to visualize the behavior of how files are used. In its simplest form, I want to light up a pixel/shape when a particular file in a directory is opened, changed/written-to, closed, or otherwise modified. Is this possible in Python. Is this possible in any language, if not Python?

Further, what modules should I look at using for such a project (both visualization and monitoring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a python Module called [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

it's cross-platform
you can get started with This [Example](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#quickstart)

Comment: This does seem to monitor changes in the file system like file or directory creation/deletion/movement/renaming/modification. Like your other answer, not completely what I was looking for, but nonetheless it seems very useful! Thank you!